# Is it bad practice to call setter properties as your _init_ method definition?

Tags: python, class, properties

I found in a couple of cases that - for some class attributes - my __init__ definition exactly resembled my @attribute.setter to an obnoxious degree, motivating example:

```
class Eg:
   __init__(self, att):
      if #correct type and form
         #do some more checks/formatting
         self._att = att

   @property
   def att(self):
      return self._att

   @att.setter
   def att(self, att):
      if #correct type and form
         #do some more checks/formatting
         self._att = att
```

my question is if simply calling the setter on object initialisation is problematic? An example:

```
class Eg:
   __init__(self, att):
      self.att = att

   @property
   def att(self):
      return self._att

   @att.setter
   def att(self, att):
      if #correct type and form
         #do some more checks/formatting
         self._att = att
```

Many thanks

Comment: I would say it is *good* practice. You probably want to apply the same validation inside `__init__` that you would elsewhere, and there is no point repeating the validation code in both `__init__` and in the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the biggest benefits of a property is that it can be introduced without breaking an existing interface. That is, if you started with

```
class Eg:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.att = att
```

then decided later that `att` had to be a positive integer, you don't have to change your existing `__init__`: you just add a property to the class:

```
class Eg:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.att = att

    @property
    def att(self):
        return self._att

    @att.setter
    def att(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("att must be a positive integer")
        self._att = value
```

With that in mind, I would say you are *expected* to use the setter inside `__init__`. Assignments inside `__init__` are not some kind of special case.